# How to update a textbox on key press using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to update the value of a textbox on every key press?

I'm doing currency conversion. So, there are two textboxes, one for the user to input the value while the other will automatically show the converted amount on every key press.

Should I use a for loop? But what should I loop?

The textboxes in the following for loop should be able to do its individual row conversion

```
<% for(int i=0; i<2; i++) { %>
 <td><input type="text" id= "amount" name="amount<%=i%>" /></td>

 <td><input type="text" id= "convertedAmount" name="convertedAmount<%=i%>" readonly/></td>
<%}%>
```

How should I get started in attempting this task?

Thanks in advance for any possible help.

Comment: use `keypress` event `myInput.addEventListener('keypress', handler)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`onkeyup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/hh465980.aspx) is best suited for your task:

```
Type amount $: <input type='text' id='amount' onkeyup="updateConverted()" >
<br>
Converted: <input type='text' id='converted' >
```

JavaScript function:

```
function updateConverted() {
    var conversionRate = 1.5;
    document.getElementById('converted').value =
                       document.getElementById('amount').value * conversionRate;
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHZKe/1/).

---

### Update (JSP `for` loop):

In the case of your `for` loop, you can just use the following jQuery code (no need to change the HTML):

```
$('input[name=amount]').each(function (_, value) {
    $(value).keyup(function () {
        var rate = 1.5;
        var convAmount = $(this).val() * rate;
        $(this).parent().next().children('input[name=convertedAmount]').val(convAmount);
    });
});
```

**[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eHZKe/2/)**.

<sub>Note: Your for loop is generating duplicated IDs. If possible, avoid that as it is invalid HTML.</sub>

Comment: this is great! it works! bt is there a way to make it work for textbox in a for loop too? thnks

Comment: I saw the for loop at the question now. Do you still need it?

Comment: yes I still need the for loop. so is there a way for me to do that? thnks

Comment: i tried bt it doesnt seem to work for my for loop...no idea wheres the error... bt i shall try again. Thnks!

Comment: i believe this line is for storing the converted value into the convertedAmount textbox rite?                $(this).parent().next().children('input[name=convertedAmount]').val(convAmount);

However sadly it seems like this line is not working for me.. is there any other way to counter this issue? thnks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple using jQuery:

```
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1" value="" onkeypress="calculation()" />

<input type="text" name="converted" id="converted" value="" />

<script>
function calculation() {
   var price = 'here is your formula';
   $('#converted').val(price);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Better would be to use `onkeyup`

Comment: @skparwal this works for me as well! bt same as above is there a way to make it work for textbox in a for loop? I tried to use .each(function()) bt i dun think its working. Thnks